# What’s the purpose of having app transport security settings in info.plist in a react native app

Tags: ios, react-native

What’s the purpose of having these settings in info plist:

1) allow arbitrary reload = true

2) exception domains —> localhost —> NSExceptionInsecureHTTLoads = yes

[image: info.plist in Xcode]

Is this just for development purposes?

Do I need to remove it when building production IPA?

Comment: Refer : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity

Comment: Could you explain it in terms of react-native scenario, usually we will use this flag in http cases during development...but I’m not sure if this is needed in a production app

Comment: You need it if you are using HTTP (Not recommended) for any request. If you are using all requests on HTTPS then you can remove this. Read the link given by @dahiya_boy for more details.